# Typescript cannot infer function arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So i have this function where i want typecsript to infer type from the arguments provided to the function but it does not seem to work. Provided is some code below .

```
type someTypeEnum = '1';
type someOtherTypeEnum = '2' | '3';
type combinedTypeEnum = someTypeEnum | someOtherTypeEnum;
type combinedTypeMap<T extends combinedTypeEnum> = T extends someTypeEnum ? number :
    T extends someOtherTypeEnum ? string : never;

export class ItemBalCore<T extends combinedTypeEnum, K extends combinedTypeMap<T>>  {
    public itemType: T;
    public itemTypeMap: K;
}

type itemBalType<T extends combinedTypeEnum, K extends combinedTypeMap<T>> =
    T extends someTypeEnum ? ItemBalCore<T, K> :
    T extends someOtherTypeEnum ? ItemBalCore<T, K> & { someOtherProp: string } :
    never;

function someFunction<T extends combinedTypeEnum, K extends combinedTypeMap<T>>
    (args: Pick<itemBalType<T, K>, 'itemType'>): Pick<itemBalType<T, K>, 'itemType'> {
    return { itemType: args.itemType }
};

const { itemType } = someFunction({ itemType: '1' }) // itemType inferred as combinedTypeEnum and not 1;
const { itemType } = someFunction({ itemType: '2', }) // itemType inferred as combinedTypeEnum and not 2;
```

At line `const { itemType } = someFunction({ itemType: '1' })` i was expecting `itemType` to be `1` but i am getting `combinedTypeEnum`.
Similarly on the next line.
 I am not sure why this is'nt  working any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: according to me you need to use real types here.   luke `string` or `string | number`

Comment: So this is a contrived example in actual use case the type in not `string | number` but some other type that that need to be conditioned on `T`.

Comment: Typescript will not be able to figure out `T` and `K` from that complicated conditional type.. why not start with `args : { itemType: T}` and figure out any return types with conditional types (although in this case there seem to be no other related types)

Comment: please check:  discriminated unions as well as Union enums and enum member types:   https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir hmmmm... but is'nt this a valid use case that needs to be supported in typescript ?

Comment: @jcuypers discriminated union will not work in this case as the return type depends on the input provided.

Comment: @AmolGupta I can't really speak to that. It can probably be done in principle, but probably the costs don't justify the implementation. And probably what you want can be achieved in another way. Your current code does not however have enough info. As it is currently written I would just go with `function someFunction<T extends combinedTypeEnum> (args: { itemType: T }): { itemType: T } {
    return { itemType: args.itemType }
};` but my guess is you have more going on there.. the code does nto however ilustrate this

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks for all the help i guess i'll just post an issue on github.